# Which is faster insert query or update in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my app,I have a requirement to insert 600 rows and each row have 10 parameters that means I am inserting 6000 data for every 5 seconds.So I am deleting the previous value and inserting 600 rows for every 5 seconds.The other way is I can update the previous data using where Clause.So wondering to know which will have least performance issue.Also if I have some millions of rows and If i want to select the data for ID 50000.Then I will write this way

```
select * from mytable where ID=50000.
```

After some time If i need the data for id 90000 then Will the sql server search from beginning ID(ID=1) for every select statement or it will directly move to ID=90000
My query is will sql server starts looking from id=1 till it matches the where clause or how it searches?

**EDIT** ID is Primay key and auto increment

Comment: deleting the previous value means : delete all data in the table ?

Comment: Of course `UPDATE` will be cheaper than `DELETE` and `INSERT`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes i am deleting all data because i do not want the previous.I need fresh data every 5 secs

Comment: Why don't you just try both out and measure?

Comment: @Mat The only way to measure that i know is capture the time before execution and after execution then the difference will let me know the time taken.I did that and found some miliseconds difference.Are there any other way to meausre?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev To update I need to make a where clause so will it not consume more time for searching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I totally agree with Aakash' answer that UPDATE is most probably the faster approach here.

---

However I would like to clear up a potential misunderstanding (or lack of understanding) on how a relational database works:

> *If i need the data for id 90000 then will the sql server search from beginning ID(ID=1) for every select statement or it will directly move to ID=90000*

Assuming `ID` is the primary key in your table (or has a unique index defined) then SQL Server will look up the row with ID=90000 directly (actually pretty much every relational database will do it that way).

Finding the row with `id=1` takes the same amount of time as finding the row with `ID=90000` or `ID=90000000`

I suggest you take some time to read the SQL Server manual to understand how a relational database works. The following topics might be interesting for you:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190659%28v=sql.100%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190623%28v=sql.100%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500155%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Additionally you might want to have a look at "Use The Index Luke": http://use-the-index-luke.com/

There is a *lot* of very good information on how indexes work and how the database uses them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Well i need some link to prove your idea.Its because In corporate world I can not say verbally to my team this is better,I have to show them proof as well.So please tell me how to do so?

Comment: @javaBeginner: see the links I added - especially "Use The Index Luke". But to be honest: this is absolut basic knowledge about relational databases and indexes.

Comment: Thanks again.Well what would you suggest me inserting will be better or update in my case(Hope you have read my question after edit)

Comment: I agree with Aakash answer: given the information you gave us: `UPDATE` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, **UPDATE is much faster** than DELETE+INSERT, it being a single command.

The bigger the table (number of and size of columns) the more expensive it becomes to delete and insert rather than update. This is because you have to pay the price of UNDO and REDO.

Also, keep in mind the actual fragmentation that occurs when DELETE+INSERT is issued opposed to a correctly implemented UPDATE will make great difference by time.

Comment: No, that's not always correct. Delete all + bulk insert can be _much_ faster than update X rows one at a time. Can generate much less logging data too.

Comment: @Mat If i go for update then i have to use where clause.So i have to write where clause 600 times.Now suppose for id =1 server will directly update for id=1.For id=10,sql server will search from ID=1 to ID=9 and when it reaches id=10 it updates.Now for ID=20,it will again search from 1 to 19 .Similarly for 599 times it will search.I think this way.Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Insert would be faster because in case of update you need to first search for the record that you are going to update and then perform the update.

This hardly seems like a valid comparison as you never have a choice whether to insert or update as the two fill two completely different needs.  :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837/cost-of-inserts-vs-update-in-sql-server this link will help :)

Comment: OP also would also have to delete in case of insert so the search overhead you mention would exist in both cases.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers In case of delete i can use delete from table.So all the data will get deleted,I will not use where clause

Comment: Well the insert also needs to "search": it needs to make sure that no unique or primary key is violated

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well in table I have one coulmn ID which is primary key and auto increment.So for inserting i use this way insert into table(x,y,z) values(1,2,3).When a new row is inserted ID value is incrmented.But you said is for inserting it will search.So i wanted to will your idea is also applicable in my case too.