# Why does updating a MySQL table through MS Access take up more than inserting a row?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, byte

I would think it would take less because here is my command:

```
UPDATE device SET Area = " + btn + " WHERE Name = 1
```

For some reason, this is 2160 bytes while inserting only requires 1500 bytes, even when I am inserting more data than I am updating. Is there a reason for this? I checked the figures using Wireshark.

Is it because of MS Access? Or is it due to simply how MySQL quering works?

Comment: When you say `"take up more"` do you mean takes more network bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an `UPDATE` like the following:

```
UPDATE device SET Area = " + btn + " WHERE Name = 1
```

you need to send information about the table, column, value and where restriction.  However, when you perform an `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO device (Area) VALUES (...)
```

you *do not* need to send the restrictions in the `WHERE` clause.  This means it takes *less* information than doing an `UPDATE` for the same values.

You can think of `INSERT` as telling the MySQL engine to go to the end of the table and create a new record, whereas `UPDATE` forces MySQL to search the entire table for the record you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post:
[Cost of Inserts vs Update in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837/cost-of-inserts-vs-update-in-sql-server)

The updates do an additional look up before updating: so you have to look up the row followed by an insert.

Insert you are just appending to the end of the table.

I would think that additional information is being send for the lookup. Not a DBA personally, but the post above could give you some insight.