# Entity Framework: Performance of AddOrUpdate() vs. looped Add()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Lets say I have a collection of 10,000 objects that I need to add to a database using Entity Framework (I recognize that EF isn't well-suited to this task, but let's run with it for now).  For the purposes of this question, we'll make the following assumptions:

1. There is only one table, with an `IDENTITY` primary key.
2. The table is empty.
3. The objects are simple -- everything is a primitive data type (int, bool, string, etc.)

I could do this in Entity Framework in one of two ways:

```
// Option 1
foreach (var item in largeCollection)
{
    _context.SomeTable.Add(item);
}

_context.SaveChanges();

// Option 2
_context.SomeTable.AddOrUpdate(largeCollection);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Is the performance of one method inherently better or worse than the other?  Or do they both devolve into an equal number of single-line `INSERT` statements?

In other words, from a performance standpoint, is there any advantage to using `Add()` over `AddOrUpdate()` (or vice-versa) when inserting multiple items into a database?

Answer (score 5):

The best answer is using AddRange. However, 
Add is by FAR way more performant than AddOrUpdate.

**AddOrUpdate**

Perform a database round-trip to every entity to check if it already exists in the destination table.

So even if your table is empty, if you use AddOrUpdate on 10,000 objects, 10,000 database roundtrip will be performed to check if the data exists.

**Add**

The Add method will add an entity in the change tracker and call the DetectChanges method after every records added.

So if you add 10,000 objects, the DetectChanges method will be called 10,000 times which can take more than 1 minutes if you have a few relation

See: [Performance-Add](http://entityframework.net/improve-ef-add-performance)

**AddRange**

The AddRange method will add all entities and will call the DetectChanges method once after all entities are added.

So if you add 10,000 objects, the DetectChanges method will be called once.

```
_context.SomeTable.AddRange(largeCollection);
```

---

In all this situation, once you call SaveChanges, 10,000 additional database round-trip will be performed to save entities which can be quite slow as well.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

*(This library is NOT free)*

This library can make your code more efficient by allowing you to save multiples entities at once. All bulk operations are supported:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So this question discusses briefly the difference between an "update" vs an "insert" in terms of database commands:

[Cost of Inserts vs Update in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837/cost-of-inserts-vs-update-in-sql-server)

Furthermore, according to the official MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx) the add or update performs what is called an "upsert" which is basically a fancy way of saying, update the row if it exists and insert the row if it doesn't.

So with this information now, it would seem logical that `Add()` is the better method.  Furthermore, given that this specific application is being used to populate a database initially (if I'm wrong on this assumption please correct me), it would seem as though doing an `AddOrUpdate()` is pointless because there is nothing to update.

Comment: If anything the OP should just test and measure both scenario's in a production like test setting and then analyze  why both are slow or one is better on the database but worse for the memory pressure or other crazy scenario's. The rest is pure speculation.

Comment: Sure they can time it and I would agree that's the safest approach to roll with, but there are differences in speed between inserts and updates at the end of the day and I was just giving a general answer with a bit of literature to help OP better understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Well, the main advantage to `AddOrUpdate` is that it can take a collection of items.  That's what made me think of it.  Where you would need to loop through the collection for an `Add`, calling `Add` once per item, you can just pass `AddOrUpdate` the entire collection all at once and let it handle it.  That's what prompted my question.  (And yep, I'm populating a database here, which is why I need to do this all at once.)

Comment: Have you checked out `AddRange()` yet?  It takes in a collection of entities to add all at once. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @AriRoth It's simple as that - if you want to **insert** records - use `Add` or `AddRange` methods. At the end, whether you use `Add`, `AddRange` or `AddOrUpdate`, the number of `INSERT` commands will be the same. `AddOrUpdate` will execute additionally the same number of `SELECT` commands though, in order to determine if it needs to `Add` or `Update` - that's he whole purpose of that method (to *add* or *update*), not that you can pass a collection.